# Why my small R functions are taking very much disk space?

Tags: r, function, storage, storing-information

I tried to save my R objects one by one so that I do not have to load all of them at once. I created this function:

```
   f_objs_save<-function(objects, dir1){
      for (obj in objects){
        print (obj)
        save(list=c(obj),file=paste0(dir1,"\\",obj,".Rdata"))
      }
    }
```

It worked but some very small functions/objects are taking a lot of space on disk and time to load, more then 50K for 10 lines functions. Another bigger functions are taking less then 1K on disk. 
[See my File Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH3ND.png)

I guess it is saving more then just the function. How can I avoid this problem and save it in a propper way ?

Comment: They're carrying their environments with them. You could try `environment(f) <- new_environment()` ..

Comment: Thanks Ben. Could you please tell me ecxatelly what is the enviroment it takes ? Is it all the objects I have created inside the function ?

Comment: the environment contains all the objects located *in the environment in which the function was created*; if you generated the function in the global workspace, then the environment contains everything in the global workspace ...

Comment: When I create functions on Rstudio, sometimes it automatically creates them in new enviroments. I would like them to be always on the Global enviroment. How could I do that without having to explict declate on every function ?